# LaTeX custom class section padding and paragraph padding

Tags: document-classes, sections-paragraphs, parskip

I am writing a cls-file for a conference template.

I like to control the padding before and after the section, subsection, subsubsection etc and I do this by the following definition:

```
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\bfseries}}%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\bfseries}}%

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\itshape}}%
```

This works fine untill I try to change from indented paragraphs to unindented parapgrah with a base line skip inbetween the paragraphs using the following:

```
\RequirePackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

But that causes extra unintended padding for my sections.

Any ideas of how to only effect text paragraphs with the parskip?

**MWE code**

*paper.tex*

```
\documentclass{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{A title}

\author{A name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Level 1}
An important text.

Some more important text.

\subsection{Level 2}
An important text.

Some more important text.t.

\subsubsection{Level 3}
An important text.

Some more important text.

\end{document}
```

*mwe.cls*

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2017/03/03 MWE paper class]

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{parskip}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\bfseries}}%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\bfseries}}%

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\itshape}}%

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\endinput
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I recommend you to have a look at KOMA-Script and its options (or if you are forced to use "standard" classes: `titlesec`). But it would be really nice, if you could post a MWE.

Comment: Normally the answer would be to simply reduce the spacing in the section declarations by the 15pt you are adding from parskip, but you can't go negative without changing the indent flag (unless you use a modified startsection0 but you can go down to 0pt (or 1sp) do you really want the spacing around headings to be tighter than the inter paragraph space?

Comment: @TeXnician - MWE added.

Comment: I would recommend to not make the spacing around headings tighter than the inter paragraph space, because this would make the paragraphs become a stronger subdivision that the headings. BTW: I you use package `parskip` you do not need to change `\parskip` and `\parindent` yourself.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I agree. However, I have not setup the rules regarding the spacing between parts this conference template uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, that the space before a heading should be less than `\parskip`, so the following does not reduce spaces before headings that are less than `\parskip`. Nevertheless, it eliminates `\parskip` after headings:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2017/03/03 MWE paper class]

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}% Change parskip's default

% Eliminate \parskip after section headings
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\@xsect}{\vskip \@tempskipa}{\vskip
  \dimexpr\@tempskipa-\parskip\relax}{}{}
% Set only vertical spaces > \parskip before section headings
\xpatchcmd{\@startsection}{\addvspace\@tempskipa}{%
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\parskip
    \addvspace{\dimexpr \@tempskipa-\parskip}%
  \fi
}{}{}

\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\bfseries}}%

\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\bfseries}}%

\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0pt}{12pt}{3pt}{\normalsize\itshape}}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pagestyle{plain}
}

\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{A title}

\author{A name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Level 1}
An important text.

Some more important text.

\subsection{Level 2}
An important text.

Some more important text.t.

\subsubsection{Level 3}
An important text.

Some more important text.

\end{document}
```

[image: ugly headings]

Caveat: I would never use such a layout. It's ugly and breaks the significance of headings.

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick, but as you point out it looks ugly :(